# PopOS - Headphones making Heart Beat sound while plugged in

Tags: audio, alsa, alsamixer

Since this morning my headphones have been making a "Heart Beat" thumping noise while plugged in. No sound plays through them. Sound plays normally through laptop speakers.

I am running Pop!_OS Version 18.10

My laptop is an:

- ASUS ROG Strix Hero Edition
- Intel Core i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
- NVidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
- 16gb RAM

I've tried the fix through AlsaMixer to turn off "loopback", but it does not appear in my version of AlsaMixer (Version 1.1.6). So I was unable to disable that.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I also tried running `pasuspender -- speaker-test -D hw:0 -c 2 -t wav` and did not hear any sound. Just the Heart Beat.

```
dylannunns@pop-os:~$ pasuspender -- speaker-test -D hw:0 -c 2 -t wav

speaker-test 1.1.6

Playback device is hw:0
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels
WAV file(s)
Rate set to 48000Hz (requested 48000Hz)
Buffer size range from 64 to 16384
Period size range from 32 to 8192
Using max buffer size 16384
Periods = 4
was set period_size = 4096
was set buffer_size = 16384
 0 - Front Left
 1 - Front Right
Time per period = 2.732280
 0 - Front Left
 1 - Front Right
Time per period = 2.986391
 0 - Front Left
 1 - Front Right
Time per period = 2.986504
 0 - Front Left
 1 - Front Right
^CGot SIGINT, exiting.
Transfer failed: Bad address
dylannunns@pop-os:~$ pasuspender -- speaker-test -D hw:1 -c 2 -t wav

speaker-test 1.1.6

Playback device is hw:1
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels
WAV file(s)
ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1820:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card
Playback open error: -2,No such file or directory
```

The details of running `amixer -D hw:0` are:

```
dylannunns@pop-os:~$ amixer -D hw:0
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono: Playback 53 [61%] [-25.50dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-65.25dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-65.25dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',2
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',3
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',4
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 63
  Front Left: Capture 39 [62%] [12.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 39 [62%] [12.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Auto-Mute Mode',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
  Item0: 'Disabled'
```

Other details:

- I'm using FireFox as my Browser
- I dual boot Windows 10 and Pop!_OS

The headphones work normally on Windows.

Comment: Some brands do a heartbeat pulse when they are not connected/not receiving any sound. Mine do that, and it is fairly annoying.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro That's annoying. Find it weird that it's never happened before in the last 5 months I've had the laptop. But it might make sense, I just got on my laptop this morning and it's not making the noise anymore and sound plays through my headphones. But restarting/turning off at any point yesterday didn't fix it. So I've no clue what the actual issue/cause was.